# How to save images from a uri to MongoDB for REST api usage #NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image, api, rest

Whilst working on a project of mine, I experienced a small predicament where I needed to save images to my mongoDB database and output them via my Rest API. I did not find much helpful documentation on the topic and it took me a few days to figure out the solution.

For people in the same situation as me I have the answers.

**Step 1**

Firstly we need to fetch the image from our uri. We will use the request npm package and **set encoding to null** by default. This is important as it will respond with our data in binary form

```
var request = require("request").defaults({ encoding: null });
...

function fetchImage(imageUri) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.get(imageUri, function (err, res, body) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(body);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

**Step 2**

Now the we have our data in binary form we can store it in our MongoDB document. *The best practice to storing images in MongoDB is by saving it in Binary form.*

```
fetchImage(URI)
      .then((binaryString) => {

        const image = new imageModel({
          image: binaryString,
        });

        image
          .save()
          .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            resolve("done");
          })
      }) 
      .catch((err) => reject(err));
```

**Step 3**

Now that our image is stored as binary in our database, we can easily retrieve and display it with our REST api.

```
function searchMongoImage(searchKey) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    imageModel
      .findOne({ primaryKey: searchKey })
      .then((doc) => {
        if (doc != null) {
          resolve(doc); // item is in db
        } else {
          reject("Item not in db"); 
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => alert(err));
  });
}

router.get("/images/search/:searchKey", function (req, res, next) {
  searchMongoImage(req.params.searchKey)
    .then((doc) => {
      res.status(200).type("png").send(doc.image);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
     //error handling and respond with a 404 page here
    });
});
```

The API will now output our binary in the browser and display it in a PNG format.

I hope that this will help someone who has encountered a similar situation and save them some time digging through unrelated forum posts :)

If anyone has questions or would like some help understanding the code feel free to ask me!

Comment: you can write your answer to related questions. you hve posted it as a question and this is not the right place

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is the best way to store images for expressjs, mongodb site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55963408/which-is-the-best-way-to-store-images-for-expressjs-mongodb-site)